# DialogFragment width shrink after specifying FEATURE_NO_TITLE

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-support-library

So here is my onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);
  ...
  return view;
}
```

And the layout itself is a LinearLayout with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

For some reason, after adding the line `getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` the dialog shrunk to wrap the contents; in fact, one of the TextViews is forced to wrap its one line into two lines.
I want the Dialog to fill the width of the screen, save some margin that I specify.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solve the problem, but I don't like the cause of the problem or the solution.

The problem was this, one of the children views was

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

changing it to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

did the trick.

Comment: live-safer! I literally searched for hours. This must be one of the weirdest android bugs.. thank you

Comment: You're my hero! Your answer saved hours for me. 
In my case a child `TextView` width was `wrap_content` which should be(!) but seems android `DialogFramgent` think differently :)

Comment: This is the wrong way to do this, despite the upvotes. See my answer for the proper way.

Answer (score 30):

Use this line in and it will be full width, regardless of the children:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
}
```

The key is `NoActionBar_MinWidth` in the theme declaration.

Comment: the other solution of making every width of views to `match_parent` wasn't good for my case. but this answer solved the problem.

Comment: That's because the other solution is the wrong way to do it. ;-)

Comment: Meet the same issue when remove dialog's title, and this code snip works perfect

Comment: requestFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE ) and setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE) can remove the title . So what is the best choice ?

Comment: that theme is deprecated 
 now, could use `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth` for API 21+

Comment: @hmac nice bro. nice

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your width in the root layout, probably you should know that the width of any window in android devices is about 360dp, so if you set the width to 344dp, you will have 16dp of space to play around with your dialog, additionally you should set your layout_gravity to center_horizontal so it will have the usual look, this will do trick.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="344dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"></FrameLayout>
```

A FrameLayout in my case, yours can be anything you need.

Answer (score -3):

Set the root view's `minWidth` property to 1000dp.